# Remove Column From Replicated Article without re-snapshoting in 2008r2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, replication

I've inherited an undocumented 2008r2 Transactional Replication set-up.

There are close to 500GB of replicated articles with lots of hidden gotchas such as Indexed views being replicated to Tables.

The Development team need to Drop 1 column from a small lookup table, and Create a new column on another Table. In addition the Triggers on the 2 tables will be modified.

How can I accomplish this without re-taking the snapshot and copying all the data over again? (Am I on a fools errand? should I just start planning for a long weekend? the sooner I have a plan the better.)

The entire Publisher database isn't replicated - only selected articles. (So my snapshot options are limited, can't restore from backup)

I've done some research but can't find anything specific to 2008R2.

Answer (score 2):

The article below talks about adding, dropping, and modifying columns in detail for 2008 R2 for various types of replication. I would start there, let me know if this is not what you were looking for.

> Replication supports a wide range of schema changes to published objects. When you make any of the following schema changes on the appropriate published object at a Microsoft SQL Server Publisher, that change is propagated by default to all SQL Server Subscribers:
>
> - ALTER TABLE
> - ALTER TABLE SET LOCK ESCALATION should not be used if schema change replication is enabled and a topology includes SQL Server 2005 or SQL Server Compact 3.5 Subscribers.ALTER VIEW
> - ALTER VIEW
> - ALTER PROCEDURE
> - ALTER FUNCTION
> - ALTER TRIGGER
>
>   ALTER TRIGGER can be used only for data manipulation language [DML] triggers because data definition language [DDL] triggers cannot be replicated.
>
> You can use replication stored procedures to specify whether these schema changes are replicated. The stored procedure that you use depends on the type of publication.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151870(v=sql.105).aspx)